# What are netimm.PNF and netxe32.PNF?

Tags: windows-7, networking

What are netimm.PNF and netxe32.PNF? What are they used for? Also, please tell me about .PNF files in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNF files are compiled versions of INF files used for software & driver setup.

Extract from [filext.com](http://filext.com/file-extension/Pnf):

> Windows (Precompiled Setup
>   Information) by Microsoft Corporation
>   A precompiled INF file. Windows
>   creates a PNF file for each INF file
>   to facilitate efficient processing. If
>   a PNF file does not exist, Setup
>   generates one for the INF file. The
>   identifying characters used for this
>   association are - Hex: 01 01

By examining the netimm.PNF file itself (or rather the non-compiled `.INF` version) we can see the following details:

```
IBMDevice         = "IBM USB Remote NDIS Network Device"
```

Unfortunately I don't have netxe32.INF on my system, but a little Googling finds me [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794143.aspx):

> Intel(R) 10 Gigabit XF/AT Server Adapters
>   9/30/2010
>
> This package is a in-box Driver Pack in the category Net. The name of the package as it > appears on disk and for use with some command-line tools is WinEmb-INF-netxe32.

So it is highly likely that this is part of the drivers for an Intel 10 Gigabit XF/AT Server Adapter

Comment: Thank you so much . But I also wanted to know about the 2 files i mentioned specifically. Anyways thanks for the info.